# Pass a Swift function to NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have some function inside another function. in function1 i want to use NSTimer to call func2 after some time like this:

```
func myFunc1()
{
   NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: ??, selector:#selector(myFunc2()), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
   func myFunc2()
   {
      // do something...
   }
}
```

What is the right "target" value that i should pass there? is it even possible?

Comment: You can't do this, declare myFunc2 as a class method

Comment: @DanielKrom, you mean _instance method on the top level in the class_ (or something like that), maybe?

Comment: @holex Yes, forgot that class method means static here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are targeting pre-iOS 10, you can't pass a function to `NSTimer` because no API was introduced at that time to support closure callbacks.

**iOS 10 and later Approach**

```
// swift 2.x users should still use NSTimer instead
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: true) { timer in
    // ...
}
```

**Generic Approach**

You can add this class, and reuse it anytime:

```
final class TimerInvocation: NSObject {

    var callback: () -> ()

    init(callback: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.callback = callback
    }

    func invoke() {
        callback()
    }
}

extension Timer {

    static func scheduleTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool, invocation: TimerInvocation) {

        Timer.scheduledTimer(
            timeInterval: timeInterval,
            target: invocation,
            selector: #selector(TimerInvocation.invoke(timer:)),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: repeats)
    }
}
```

With this class, you can simply do this now:

```
let invocation = TimerInvocation {
    /* invocation code here */
}

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: invocation, selector:#selector(TimerInvocation.invoke), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

You don't have to worry about retaining the `invocation` variable since it is retained by `NSTimer`

Comment: You are the MAN ! :)

Comment: This does point to an open question. Is Swift going to have a nice clean, modern, Swift-like timer function as part of it's standard library? It should take a closure as it's parameter. The Dispatch class in Swift 3 is close...

Comment: @DuncanC Yeah, Foundation framework as well as others are slowly but surely gonna adapt to Swift over time. For now, the best you can do is write thin wrappers to simplify your Swift development. When the new APIs come out, removing the unnecessary dependencies will be easy. Check out [kitz](http://kitz.io) for example. It wraps `NSNotificationCenter` so you can pass closures.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3, the new `Timer` has a factory method that takes a closure:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool, block: (Timer) -> Void)
```

In your case, you could call it like this using trailing closure syntax:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in
    // do something
}
```

---

**Note:** This is only available in iOS 10 or newer.